# Changing GWT TabPanel name

Tags: java, gwt, tabpanel

I'm trying to make a dynamic TabPanel in GWT. I want the text in the TabPanel to change depending on what a user types in a TextBox. For example, typing "Tab one" would change the tab text to "Tab one". However, I can't seem to find the method for changing the name of the tab. getTitle() just returns the title, and not the actual text. Does anyone know how to do this?

One way might be to delete the tab and recreate it with the same contents, but I'd really like to avoid this if possible.
Thanks.

Comment: TabPanel.getTabBar() and then TabBar.setTabText() ?

Comment: Perfect! I was only looking for a TabPanel.setText() or a TabPanel.getTabBar().getTab().setText().

Answer (score 2):

Well "onnoweb" already gave the correct answer, but here you have a demo example.

```
package stefank.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Unit;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TabLayoutPanel;

public class _02_GWTAnimation implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {

        // Create a tab panel
        final TabLayoutPanel tabPanel = new TabLayoutPanel(2.5, Unit.EM);
        tabPanel.setHeight("100px");
        tabPanel.setAnimationDuration(1000);
        tabPanel.getElement().getStyle().setMarginBottom(10.0, Unit.PX);

        // Add a home tab
        String[] tabTitles = {"hello", "world"};
        HTML homeText = new HTML("Lorem ipsum");
        tabPanel.add(homeText, tabTitles[0]);


        // Add a tab
        HTML moreInfo = new HTML("Lorem ipsum");
        tabPanel.add(moreInfo, tabTitles[1]);

        // Return the content
        tabPanel.selectTab(0);
        tabPanel.ensureDebugId("cwTabPanel");

        RootPanel.get().add(tabPanel);

        Button changeText = new Button("change Text");
        changeText.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                tabPanel.setTabText(0, "new Title");                
            }
        });
        RootPanel.get().add(changeText);

    }
}
```